# Powershell LDAP Filter

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Is there any `LDAP` Filter which searches for substring of letters?

What I was trying to do is this one:

```
Get -ADUser Filter {(|(sAMAccountName -like "x*")(sAMAccountName -like "y*")(sAMAccountName -like "z*"))}
```

I want to replace all `sAMAccountName` filters with `sAMAccountNAME -like "x-z"`

What is the search Filter to use if I am looking for `sAMAccountNames` in between `(a-h)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/c8c050a5-ab79-414b-83f8-3f83806a9e28/getaduser-with-user-names-beginning-with-a-through-j?forum=ITCG). But basically, you can use >= and <= with characters in LDAP filters, so this would work:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter "(&(sAMAccountName>=a)(sAMAccountName<=h))"
```

[Here's the full documentation](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5392.active-directory-ldap-syntax-filters.aspx) on how you can construct LDAP filters.

Comment: Thank you...that answered my question